# How well do ROMS run on R-Pi?

Tags: retropie

I'm looking at SNES Games. I've been looking into making mine into an Emulator Machine but im wondering if anyone had any experience in how "well" they run.

I'm sure some might have issues, but I'm mostly concerned with slowdown/etc...

Comment: For emulation purposes you look at CPU power.  A common comparison is to a 300 MHz Pentium which is old but still much faster than what you want to emulate.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=42152

> by pudding » Mon Apr 29, 2013 9:20 am
>
> I've released a SNES emulator
>   for the Pi. It's based on v1.39 of SNES9X and highly "tuned" for the
>   Raspberry Pi (dispmanx, ALSA audio, SDL for input), with configurable
>   input. Most games run at full speed. Yes it's a very old version of
>   SNES9X but it runs at a good speed on the Pi but won't play a number
>   of the later SNES roms.
>
> Designed for those who just like to "plugin" and play.  :) Hope you
>   enjoy it!
>
> Get it from the Pi Store http://store.raspberrypi.com/projects/pisnes
>   (preferred version as it will install correctly and use the most
>   up-to-date version).
>
> Homepage is http://code.google.com/p/pisnes/ with the source code,
>   binaries and for logging issues - for those who don't like the Pi
>   Store.